# Можно ли поменять width блока полученного через querySelector

Tags: javascript, css

Можно ли как-то поменять ширину блока полученного таким способом:

```
for (let i=0, length=that.item.length;i<length; i++) {
        itemstyle = window.getComputedStyle(that.item[i]);
        itemstyle.width = parseInt(size.width)/that.options.kol_item + 'px';
    };
```

ругается на то что параметр width только для чтения.
Может существуют другие способы динамически менять ширину блока через таблицу стилей.

Comment: ``getComputedStyle`` возвращает read-only объект. Чтобы установить значение css-свойства, воспользуйтесь ``elem.style.width``

Comment: Спасибо. Чет и вправду полез я в дебри.